# Zoom - is it GUI or Core or Apps responsibility

Tags: linux, xfce, xubuntu

I use XFCE + Xubuntu
When I zoom it using 
Settings->Settings Editor->Xsettings->DPI
Some applications doesn't change it's fonts size until I restart it, like PHPStorm.
Is it responsibility of XFCE GUI, or of Ubuntu/Linux core, or PHPStorm?
If I'll change to f.e. Mint or CentOS, will it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe DPI scaling is the responsibility of the Xorg server.

[The ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Display_size_and_DPI) on the subject also mentions this:

> GTK very often overrides the server's DPI via the optional Xresource
> Xft.dpi. To find out whether this is happening to you, check with:
>
> `$ xrdb -query | grep dpi`
>
> With GTK library versions since 3.16, when this variable is not
> otherwise explicitly set, GTK sets it to 96. To have GTK apps obey the
> server DPI you may need to explictly set Xft.dpi to the same value as
> the server.

It looks like some window managers which handle DPI changes also do so through Xorg.

> The Xft.dpi resource is the method by which some desktop
> environments optionally force DPI to a particular value in personal
> settings. Among these are KDE and TDE.